# Python Upper and Lowercase Criteria in String Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that scans a string and finds all instances of "hello", with both capital and lowercase letters. The problem is that while a simple

```
the_list = re.compile(r'hello')
```

would suffice for only "hello" in the string, I would like the expression to be able to find all versions of "hello" with both capitalized and lowercase letters, such as:

```
Hello, HELlo, hEllo, HELLO, heLLO, etc.
```

I have also tried:

```
the_list = re.compile(r'[a-z][A-Z]hello')
```

But no luck. Could anyone explain a better way to write this regular expression?

Comment: Use: `the_list = re.compile(r'hello', re.I)` to make it ignore case

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use the `IGNORECASE` flag the `re` module provides:

```
the_list = re.compile(r'hello', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

If you want to write less, this is sufficient enough:

```
the_list = re.compile(r'hello', re.I)
```

Since `re.I` is just another way of writing `re.IGNORECASE`

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.I)'s the documentation for `re.IGNORECASE`:

> Perform case-insensitive matching; expressions like `[A-Z]` will match
>   lowercase letters, too. This is not affected by the current locale and
>   works for Unicode characters as expected.

Comment: Might be useful to note that `flags=` is optional, so that, `re.I` is enough

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder ok, I added another example, also I kept the first one because it is more clear and readable. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will ignore the case in the word you're searching for.

**NOTE:** **re.I** refers to **IGNORECASE** flag.

```
hello = re.compile(r'hello', re.I)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way.

```
the_list = re.compile(r'hello(?i)')
```